# Caculating mean and standard deviation of every column of csv file in python

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to pre-process a data set by removing '?' from every data point and then calculating the mean and standard deviation for every column. I am getting the below error:

> IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'outputFile'

Here is my code:

```
import csv
import sys
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter
class PreProcessDataSet:
    def standardize(self) :
        special_chars = set('?')
        inputFile = open(sys.argv[1], 'rb')
        print ('Input file as entered is : ', inputFile)
        outputFile = open(sys.argv[2],'wb')
        print ('Output file as entered is : ', outputFile)
        writer = csv.writer(outputFile)
        for row in csv.reader(inputFile):
            if not set(''.join(row)) & special_chars:
                writer.writerow(row)
                print row


    column_totals = Counter()
    with open('outputFile') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        row_count = 0.0
        for row in reader:
            for column_idx, column_value in enumerate(row):
                try:
                    n = float(column_value)
                    column_totals[column_idx] += n
                except ValueError:
                    print "Error -- ({}) Column({}) could not be converted to float!".format(column_value,
                                                                                                 column_idx)
            row_count += 1.0

    # row_count is now 1 too many so decrement it back down
    row_count -= 1.0

    column_indexes = column_totals.keys()
    column_indexes.sort()

    # calculate per column averages using a list comprehension
    averages = [column_totals[idx] / row_count for idx in column_indexes]
    print averages
obj = PreProcessDataSet()
obj.standardize()
```

Can some one please point out where I am going wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

If the error is "permission denied" then definitely you might not have full access to the system you are using,

OR

Check the logic of your list indexes you are using,
Wrong iteration/Range also gives same error as that of yours.

OR

You don't have sufficient permissions to write to the root directory.